# Which one is correct: "I have a dilemma" or I am in a "dilemma"?

Tags: grammar

Hi ^^ I just wanted to know if it's okay to say I have a dilemma, or I'm in a dilemma. Or are they both okay?

Comment: Identical question asked on our sister site https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105647/be-in-a-dilemma-vs-have-a-dilemma

Comment: For me, a Canadian, "have a dilemma" is more natural

Comment: It can be many other things: to be faced with a dilemma, to experience a dilemma and so on.

Comment: There is also “to be on the horns of a dilemma.”

Answer (score 1):

The traditional use is "to be in a dilemma" but in recent times, the usage "to have a dilemma" has become more common.

As [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28have+a+dilemma+%2B+has+a+dilemma%29%2Cin+a+dilemma&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28have%20a%20dilemma%20%2B%20has%20a%20dilemma%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20dilemma%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(have%20a%20dilemma%20%2B%20has%20a%20dilemma)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20dilemma%3B%2Cc0) shows, the form "in a dilemma" is from 6 to 30 times more common than the sum of the "has/have a dilemma"" forms. The form with "in" is clearly favored. But the forms using "to have" are common enough that we must consider them an acceptable part of English, at least over the past few decades.

[image: Ngram Chart showing frequency of use between “in a dilemma” and “has/have a dilemma”]

Comment: Even though OP didn't ask about it, can you also address "face a dilemma"? Including it in the ngram shows that it falls somewhere between the other two phrases in usage.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Personally I would much prefer to say "he faced a dilemma". I would also accept being "in a dilemma". But the verb "have" to my mind involves possession of some kind and a "dilemma" is surely not something you possess but is an awkward fact of life with which you are confronted - which you can find yourself "in" or "facing".

Comment: But you could of course say you "have a dilemma on your mind".

Answer (score 1):

*”I have a dilemma”* or *” I am in a dilemma”* - these two are the same. In either, the speaker faces a very difficult choice between two options. In my opinion, the second sentence is the more common of the two.